# How to implement simple protocol using Actors and Akka?

Tags: scala, protocols, akka, fsm

What is the right approach to implement following using Akka and Actors?

I need to call remote REST service and pass set of parameters and a specific date.
But my app is getting the set of input parameters and a date range.
So if date range is 365 days, app needs to make 365 calls to remote service, than process all output data (for all days in range) and save results of this processing in database.

The initial call to the REST service will not return results immediately, it will rather return some "request id". App will need to call another REST API to check the request status until it is "completed". Than it needs to get results by calling yet another REST API.

The initial call or any subsequent may as well just fail with error, than it should be retried after specific delay.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution within akka than `Actors` directly.  This type of problem can be solved with the [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/snapshot/scala/http/index.html) library which uses Streams (that utilize Actors "underneath the hood").

You first need an `ActorSystem` and `ActorMaterializer`:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

import actorSystem.dispatcher
```

Then [establish a connection](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/snapshot/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html) with the request-id service:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Flow}

import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}

val idServiceUrl = "idServiceUrl.com"

val requestIDFlow : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]]  = 
  Http().outgoingConnection(idServiceUrl)
```

The question was not specific about the "set of parameters and a specific date".  It was also not specific on how those parameters and date should form an HttpRequest:

```
type ParametersType = ???
type DateType = ???

def paramsToIDRequest(paramaters : ParametersType, date : DateType) : HttpRequest = 
  ???
```

This method can then be used to query for a request-id:

```
type IDType = ???

//converts the http response from the ID service into an ID
def httpResponseToID(httpResponse : HttpResponse) : IDType = ???

val requestIDFuture : Future[IDType] = 
  Source.single(parametersToIDRequest(...))
        .via(requestIDFlow)
        .map(httpRequestToID)
        .runWith(Sink.head)
```

Similar techniques can be used to the get the status and finally get the results...